# Optimizing Query based on Inserting into multiple columns into target table from one column of a source table

Tags: sql, hive, query-optimization, hiveql

I am trying to insert values from one column of a table to multiple columns of another table based on conditions. I have prepared the query but it's getting stuck at 80% of the MapReduce phase

I am using hive 1.1.0.
Currently, I am setting below, before executing the queries

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set parquet.compression=SNAPPY;
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
set mapreduce.map.speculative=false;
set mapreduce.reduce.speculative=false;
set hive.mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false;
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb=15000;
set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx2400m;
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=5000;
set mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx2400m;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=1024000000;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=1024000000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;
```

Kindly provide suggestions to run this query perfectly in the hive.

```
      select 
        IDENTIFICADOR_ID,
        ESTADO,
        FECHA_ESTADO,
        MUNICIPIO_ID,
        TIPO_ID,
        NOMBRE_COMPLETO,
        VALOR_PLAN_FACTURACION,
        VALOR_ESTADO_SERVICIO,
        VALOR_PAQUETE,
        VALOR_ACCESP,
        VALOR_TIPO_BANDA_ANCHA,
        VALOR_VELOCIDAD_ACCESO,
        descripcion_ltcar,
        DESCRIPCION_PLAN_OPEN,
        ESTADO_FNX_PLANES_FACTURACION,
        load_date from(
        select a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID,
        a.ESTADO,
        a.FECHA_ESTADO,
        a.MUNICIPIO_ID,
        b.TIPO_ID,
        b.NOMBRE_COMPLETO,
        a1.valor as VALOR_PLAN_FACTURACION,
        b1.valor as VALOR_ESTADO_SERVICIO,
        c1.valor as VALOR_PAQUETE,
        d1.valor as VALOR_ACCESP,
        e1.valor as VALOR_TIPO_BANDA_ANCHA,
        m1.valor as VALOR_VELOCIDAD_ACCESO,
        d.descripcion_ltcar,
        e.DESCRIPCION_PLAN_OPEN,
        e.estado as ESTADO_FNX_PLANES_FACTURACION,
        '2019-05-22' as load_date from 
        db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_IDENTIFICADORES_bs as a,db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_LISTAS_TCARACTERISTICAS_bs d 
       right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=2005)a1
on a1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=132 )b1 
on b1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=2879)c1
on c1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=2093)d1 
on d1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=120)e1 
on e1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=33)f1 
on f1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=4430)g1 
on g1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=2123)h1 
on h1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=4389)i1 
on i1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=201)j1 
on j1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=4388)k1 
on k1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=37)l1 
on l1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
right join  (select valor,IDENTIFICADOR_ID  
from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs where caracteristica_id=124)m1
    on m1.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID
        inner join db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CLIENTES_bs as b
        on a.CLIENTE_ID=b.CLIENTE_ID
        inner join db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_PLANES_FACTURACION_bs as e
        on a.PRODUCTO_ID=e.PRODUCTO_ID
        and a.SERVICIO_ID=e.SERVICIO_ID
        and a.EMPRESA_ID=e.EMPRESA_ID
        and a.MUNICIPIO_ID=e.MUNICIPIO_ID
        where a.TIPO_ELEMENTO_ID in ('CUENTA','TELEV','TO')
        and d.caracteristica_id=124)t
```

Comment: Is it possible to possible to optimize the existing query without joins?

Comment: No, it is not possible to optimize without joins. rewrite using explicit join syntax.

Comment: Updated my query

Comment: This is completely different of what it was before. wow

Comment: @leftjoin can you help provide  some modification to tune this

Comment: Without knowing all tables structure and data it is not possble to help unfortunately. All these joins look strange. why join with d is only ON constant :  d.caracteristica_id=124, does it not  produce some Cartesian data? left joins inside subqueries a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, m1 make no sense to me because LEFT table is not used in select.

Comment: It is being used to getting the value c.valor and c.identificador in the subquery

Comment: Left-joined table in the subquery left join db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_IDENTIFICADORES_bs a is not used? columns are taken from c table only.

Comment: I have further tuned this. But still its taking time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table `FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs` can be joined only one time, use case statements with aggregation:

```
select 
    IDENTIFICADOR_ID,
    ESTADO,
    FECHA_ESTADO,
    MUNICIPIO_ID,
    TIPO_ID,
    NOMBRE_COMPLETO,
    VALOR_PLAN_FACTURACION,
    VALOR_ESTADO_SERVICIO,
    VALOR_PAQUETE,
    VALOR_ACCESP,
    VALOR_TIPO_BANDA_ANCHA,
    VALOR_VELOCIDAD_ACCESO,
    descripcion_ltcar,
    DESCRIPCION_PLAN_OPEN,
    ESTADO_FNX_PLANES_FACTURACION,
    load_date 
    from
    (
    select 
    a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID,
    a.ESTADO,
    a.FECHA_ESTADO,
    a.MUNICIPIO_ID,
    b.TIPO_ID,
    b.NOMBRE_COMPLETO,
    max(case when caracteristica_id=2005 then c.valor end) as VALOR_PLAN_FACTURACION,
    max(case when caracteristica_id=132  then c.valor end) as VALOR_ESTADO_SERVICIO,
    max(case when caracteristica_id=2879 then c.valor end) as VALOR_PAQUETE,
    max(case when caracteristica_id=2093 then c.valor end) as VALOR_ACCESP,
    max(case when caracteristica_id=120  then c.valor end) as VALOR_TIPO_BANDA_ANCHA,
    max(case when caracteristica_id=124  then c.valor end) as VALOR_VELOCIDAD_ACCESO,
    d.descripcion_ltcar,
    e.DESCRIPCION_PLAN_OPEN,
    e.estado as ESTADO_FNX_PLANES_FACTURACION,
    '2019-05-22' as load_date 
    from  db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_IDENTIFICADORES_bs as a, 
          db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_LISTAS_TCARACTERISTICAS_bs d --this join needs to be fixed, there is no ON condition. This is CROSS JOIN. It is acceptable if table d returns only one row
          inner join (select * from db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CONFIGURACIONES_IDENTIF_bs c where caracteristica_id in (2005,132,2879,2093,120,124)) c on c.IDENTIFICADOR_ID =  a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID --join only one time with this table
          inner join db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_CLIENTES_bs as b on a.CLIENTE_ID=b.CLIENTE_ID
          inner join db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_PLANES_FACTURACION_bs as e on a.PRODUCTO_ID=e.PRODUCTO_ID
                                                                           and a.SERVICIO_ID=e.SERVICIO_ID
                                                                           and a.EMPRESA_ID=e.EMPRESA_ID
                                                                           and a.MUNICIPIO_ID=e.MUNICIPIO_ID
    where a.TIPO_ELEMENTO_ID in ('CUENTA','TELEV','TO')
      and d.caracteristica_id=124
    group by 
    a.IDENTIFICADOR_ID,
    a.ESTADO,
    a.FECHA_ESTADO,
    a.MUNICIPIO_ID,
    b.TIPO_ID,
    b.NOMBRE_COMPLETO,
    d.descripcion_ltcar,
    e.DESCRIPCION_PLAN_OPEN,
    e.estado as ESTADO_FNX_PLANES_FACTURACION
    )t
```

Also join with `db_trusted_common_zone.FNX_LISTAS_TCARACTERISTICAS_bs` still needs to be fixed. It is **without ON condition and works as a cross join.**

Also these values are too high:

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=1024000000;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=1024000000;
```

Try to reduce x2 or even x4 times or more to increase parallelizm.

Comment: Further, I was able to tune it by changing the order of joins and using intermediate tables.

Comment: @Durga also this and d.caracteristica_id=124 can be moved to the join ON condition. But first of all you need to fix CROSS JOIN. It looks like ON condition is missing